# Appendices instead of chapters

Tags: appendices

Hello: I am writing a document with document class `book` and another one with document class `report`. Both have 5 chapters, but curiously the fourth and fifth chapters are named A (with subsections A.1, A.2, etc..) and B (with subsections B.1, B.2, etc..) instead of 4 (with subsections 4.1, 4.2, etc..) and 5 (with subsections 5.1, 5.2, etc..), respectively. I am using neither the `\appendix` command nor the `appendix` package.

This is my document (`chapters/` is the folder where the chapters are included) and each of the sections starts with `\chapter{title of the chapter}`. I am sorry to include all the packages I am using, but I prefer to post a question as comprehensive as possible.

It'd be amazing if anyone can lend me a hand. Thank you.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\allowdisplaybreaks 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{kpfonts} % for nice fonts 
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage{booktabs} % for nice tables 
\usepackage{bm} % for bold math 
\usepackage{listings} % for inserting code 
\usepackage{verbatim} % useful for program listings 
\usepackage{color,soul} 
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref} \usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes} 
\usepackage{lscape} 
\setlength{\parindent}{0em} 
\setlength{\parskip}{1.1em} 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{array} 
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{6cm}} \usepackage{dcolumn} 
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{4mm} 
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{2cm} 
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} 
\usepackage{pdfpages} 
\usepackage{dirtytalk} 
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry} 
\usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib} 
\usepackage{chapterbib} 
\allowdisplaybreaks 
\pagestyle{myheadings} 
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{bbding} 
\addtolength{\skip\footins}{2pc plus 5pt} 
\usepackage{chngcntr} 
\counterwithin{figure}{chapter} 
\counterwithin{table}{chapter} 
\counterwithin{equation}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter*{Abstract}

\clearpage \tableofcontents 
\clearpage \listoftables 
\clearpage \listoffigures

\include{chapters/introduction} 
\include{chapters/chap1} 
\include{chapters/chap2} 
\include{chapters/chap3} 
\include{chapters/chap4} 
\include{chapters/chap5} 
\include{chapters/conclusions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that somewhere in `chapters/chap3` there's an `\appendix` command.

Comment: If you comment out the `\include{chapters/chap3}` line, it's likely that the numbering will show the change. If it doesn't the problem is at the beginning of the `chapters/chap4` file.

Comment: Thank you both so much for taking the time to reply. Don Hosek is right; I had used \appendix in chapter 3 right before two anexes I had included there, which was totally unnecessary ... I thank you again and send you my regards, Juan